# Silly name maker Tutorial

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

In the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/first-app).  I'm focusing on the "Build your first App with Dialogflow". I'm at "Build Fulfillment" step and downloading node.js.  I'm currently waiting for my company to approve the install of this software but want to continue on with my tutorial.  I figured I'd be able to copy the package.json and index.js code that is provided and use the Inline Editor, however when I try and deploy I get the following error

"The deployment of your Cloud Function failed:
Function load error: Node.js module defined by file index.js is expected to export function named dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"

What am I missing here?

Side question:  Do I have to use node.js or can I use another IDE to develop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all - you can use any language and platform you want to build your Action. However, only a node.js library is provided by Google. If you want to use a different language, there are a few third-party libraries available, or you can just parse and generate the JSON yourself.

As far as the Dialogflow inline editor, it assumes there is a function exported with the name `dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment` that will be called. The example tutorial has that with the name `sillyNameMaker` in a line that looks like this:

```
exports.sillyNameMaker = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
```

This is how Firebase Cloud Functions determines which function to call and the URL path for HTTPS calls. You should be able to change this to something like

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
```

Comment: Great! If it helps, upvoting and/or accepting the answer is always appreciated.

Comment: I didn't realize I could "accept" the answer.  I've done that now.  Thanks again!